# Hazelcast cache data volume

Tags: java, hazelcast

In my project, planning to use Hazelcast cache to improve the performance instead of querying the Database table each time. In the database table there could be close to 1 million records. The application is using cluster environment (Minimum 4 nodes).

Can I load whole 1 million records in to cache? 
With 1 million records in cache, will there be any performance issues while retrieving the data?
What is the ideal number of records that can be stored in cache?

Comment: There will be a lot of performance issue (RAM & CPU) from the moment you start using hazelcast. The ideal size of cache should be fine-tuned in accordance to your application usage & infrastructure. The comment might look trivial but it is a non-trivial job to actually architecture your application to properly use hazelcast. Way above the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can keep 1 million records in the Hazelcast map but do note that the get & put operations are expensive as they involve network operations internally to distribute data. This will matter if you are trying to go through a set of keys or looping through a lot of entries.
It is advised to partition your data in such a way that you hit the cluster map less number of times.
e.g., If there is a Employee table and you want to cache all the employee data. Depending on your usage & get operations, partition the whole table into multiple chunks. In this case, group employee records into geography wise or location wise or allocated project wise etc. Then have unique key that can go into Hazelcast map and value can be a set/map of employee records. In this way, you will hit the cluster once(& hence network once) and then process the records in the local JVM.

In your case, if you are pulling & processing the records one at a time then it makes sense to push all the records into the map and do get operation on the unique key. You can have a background operation that takes care of refreshing of records in the map.

Also, you can make use of NearCache for keeping a copy in the local at the client side for faster access. It is part of client configurations and if you enable the NearCache, the first get operation will pull the entry from cluster map and keeps it in local so the subsequent operations would be as good as local map. You can set the timeout for entry types so it can refresh the entry from cluster after certain time. By default, the entry gets invalidated whenever the corresponding entry is updated in the Distributed map.

Comment: Two more things to keep in mind: (1) you may use a [near-cache](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#near-cache), that transparently maintains a local copy of data so get operations become local (and cheaper). As of Hazelcast 3.8 near cache is eventually consistent. (2) if you need to process entries, use an [EntryProcessor](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#entry-processor) to avoid the cost of roundtrip. As an added bonus, the EntryProcessor is guaranteed to execute atomically with respect to other operations on the same key.

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I forgot to include NearCache. Will add reference.